# Odoo model operation throws "expected singleton" exception

Tags: python, odoo

I want to perform an invoice operation with two records at the same time and I get this error. How do I solve it?

> ValueError: Expected singleton: account.invoice(481, 482)

Comment: Please share your attempt code and provide as many as possible details in the question. Currently, your question doesn't match with SO standards. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BhaveshOdedra The question is very clear if you know something about Odoo. Please reopen.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by starting your code like this:

```
def function(self):
    for invoice in self:
        # logic per invoice here
```

Comment: I try that. Tks!